# centering an element in css circle (width and height given by ems)

Tags: html, css, positioning, centering

hello I am trying to center an element  inside a css circle. I tried few difference ways, but didn't get it working.

Here an [JsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/7xEbY/3/)

HTML

```
<div class="large-columns">
        <div class="circle-holder">
                <span class="circle"><h1>h tag</h1></span>
        </div>                  
</div>
```

CSS

```
.circle {
    display: block;
    width: 10em;
    height: 10em;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 50%;
}    
    h1 {
      text-align: center;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;

}
```

Comment: fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/7xEbY/3/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the to be aligned element is an inline-block, then you can do it with `line-height`.

Update your CSS code to this:

```
.circle {
    display: block;
    width: 10em;
    height: 10em;
    border-radius: 50%;

    line-height: 10em;
    text-align: center;

    background: red;
}
```

[JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/7xEbY/12/)

Comment: Will _only_ work for a single _line_ of `h1` text (just to warn @solom), so if your `h1` are only ever on one line, this is a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

css

```
    h1 {
      text-align: center;
      position: relative;
      top: 50%;
}
```

change to `position:relative` check [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/7xEbY/5/)

Comment: It is not incorrect, but this solution is dependant on `font-size`. If the font-size is relative, for example `body { font-size:2em; }`, the hard `60px` will not vertically align the `<h1>`.

Answer (score 0):

change `position:` in `h1` to `relative`. After that I would explicitly define the `top` to `60px;` which would center the header.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8YqvT/3/)

**EDIT:**

You can also change the `top` in CSS with percent values as well.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, yes, this is compatible on all major browsers and won't cause any harmful bugs or glitches.

Comment: However Sven's answer is the way to go. :)

Comment: I always study HTML and CSS by using Google Chrome's "Inspect Element" by right-clicking any online webpage.